# no rule to make target main.h

Tags: makefile, g++

I can compile and run my c++ program on my raspberry pi.  However I am trying to make a makefile, because the command line is getting a little long.  I've never manually made one before.  I had grabbed a sample makefile, and attempted to change it for me. However I get a "No rule to make target `main.h`.

This will compile the game properly

`g++ -o EGM_Test_8 version1_1_077.cpp -lwiringPi -lncurses -lfreeimageplus -lgraphics`

Here is the makefile

```
#This sample makefile has been setup for a project which contains the following files: main.h, ap-main.c, ap-main.h, ap-gen.c, ap-gen.h   Edit as necessary for your project  #Change output_file_name.a below to your desired executible filename

#Set all your object files (the object files of all the .c files in your project, e.g. main.o my_sub_functions.o )
OBJ = version1_1_077.o 

#Set any dependant header files so that if they are edited they cause a complete re-compile (e.g. main.h some_subfunctions.h some_definitions_file.h ), or leave blank
DEPS = 

#Any special libraries you are using in your project (e.g. -lbcm2835 -lrt `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` ), or leave blank
LIBS = -lwiringPi -lncurses -lfreeimageplus

#Set any compiler flags you want to use (e.g. -I/usr/include/somefolder `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` ), or leave blank
CFLAGS = -g

#Set the compiler you are using ( gcc for C or g++ for C++ )
CC = g++

#Set the filename extensiton of your C files (e.g. .c or .cpp )
EXTENSION = .cpp

#define a rule that applies to all files ending in the .o suffix, which says that the .o file depends upon the .c version of the file and all the .h files included in the DEPS macro.  Compile each object file
%.o: %$(EXTENSION) $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

#Combine them into the output file
#Set your desired exe output file name here
EGM_Test_8: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

#Cleanup
.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f *.o *~ core *~
t
```

I get an error about `main.h`, however I'm not using a `main.h` file.

Comment: How does you use `make` command?

Comment: I tried running at the terminal   "make version1_1_077"

Comment: I don't see how that makefile could give that error. I suggest you delete the makefile, then try `make version1_1_077.o` and see what happens.

Comment: Please quote the exact error. Most likely, your `main.c` includes `main.h`, which doesn't exist.